# How do I connect the NetBeans profiler to a specic remote instance

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, profiler

I have a remote GlassFish server that has a node agent configured. The instance I want to start in profiling mode is controlled by the node agent.

I've installed and calibrated the remote pack and I've modified my domain.xml for the specific instance as follows:

```
<profiler enabled="true" name="NetBeansProfiler">
    <jvm-options>-agentpath:/home/glassfish/glassfish/profiler-server-6.0rc1-linux/lib/deployed/jdk16/linux/libprofilerinterface.so=/home/glassfish/glassfish/profiler-server-6.0rc1-linux/lib,5140</jvm-options>
</profiler>
```

Now at this point NetBeans tells you to start the domain with the --verbose command but in my case I'm trying to start an instance and "asadmin start-instance" doesn't support --verbose. I've checked the server.log but I'm not seeing any error nor any language that says it's waiting when I try to start the instances.

However, I think GlassFish is properly configured and my NetBeans setup is the issue. Where I think the issue might be is trying to specify the port. If I leave the port off, it just tries to connect forever. If I put the port on it just closes the dialog and the status shows "Inactive".

[image: NetBeans Profiler setup page 1]
[image: NetBeans Profiler setup page 2]

UPDATE:
It seems there might be a bug with GF2. After verifying everything and getting the server so that it was listening, the following exception is thrown

Could not load Logmanager "com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ServerLogManager"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ServerLogManager
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:166)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.(LogManager.java:156)

According to this URL, http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-3256 it's a known issue and won't be fixed until GF3.

Anyway, my question was about how to connect to a specific instance and I think that was answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not include the port number in the hostname field. The port number is taken from the global  profiler settings.

Comment: If I don't include the port number then how do I specify the specific instance? I could have multiple instances on the host.

Comment: You need to setup the appropriate port number in the profiler IDE options.

Comment: For anyone else following this. In NetBeans go to Tools\Options, then click on the profiler tab. In there is a Communication Port entry.

I'll try it and post an update.